# How to change the colors on a Led Matrix

Tags: arduino

Hello i would like help with chagning the colors if it is possible because i just cant figure it out..
I have two questions one is it possible to do Hex colors in arduino with a rgb led matrix and if so how would you do grey. ill post my code down below it displays a red line.

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>   // Core graphics library
#include <RGBmatrixPanel.h> // Hardware-specific library

// pinout:
#define CLK 8  
#define OE  9
#define LAT 10
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2
#define D   A3

RGBmatrixPanel matrix(A, B, C, D, CLK, LAT, OE, false);

void setup(){
matrix.begin();

}

void loop() {

matrix.drawPixel(10, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(11, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(12, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(13, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(14, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(15, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(16, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(17, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(18, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(19, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(20, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(21, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
matrix.drawPixel(22, 8, matrix.Color333(7, 0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grey is equal parts red, green, and blue.

```
matrix.drawPixel(10, 8, matrix.Color333(4, 4, 4));
```

Note that (0,0,0) is black and (7,7,7) is white. Any value in between (with R=G=B) gives a shade of grey.